# Wordpress Cookies instead of PHP Sessions

Tags: wordpress, cookies, phpmyadmin

I had been using PHP SESSIONs but due to a plugin conflict, I have recoded my site to use $Cookies. I have the following code, which sets up a Cookie and writes it to a database table.  This all works OK, and the table entry is correctly saved and updated. But my database table ends up with other entries (one for each run of the page).  How can I avoid these extra lines being saved?

```
add_action('init', 'init_jamer_cookies');

  function init_jamer_cookies ()    {
    global $wpdb;
    global $wp;
    global $woocommerce;
    $jamer_session_id=$_COOKIE['jamer_session_id'];
    if(!isset($jamer_session_id)) {
            $time=current_time( 'timestamp' ) + ( DAY_IN_SECONDS * 7 );
            $randomString=generateRandomString(20);
              setcookie('jamer_session_id', $randomString, $time, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
              $tablename='jamercookies';
              $tablename_all = $wpdb->prefix.$tablename;
              $wpdb->insert($tablename_all, array('jamer_session_id' => $randomString, 'schoolid' => '' ));

    }
       return;
       }

function generateRandomString($length ) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
//

add_shortcode('mc_check_access1','mc_check_access');

// Checks access
function mc_check_access() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $wp;
    global $woocommerce;

  $url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'home' );
  if ($_POST["submit"] ) {
    $schoolname = $_POST["SchoolName"];
    $schoollogin = $_POST["SchoolLogin"];

    $schoolset==0;
    $schoolset = set_jamer_session ($schoolname, $schoollogin);
    if ($schoolset==1 ) {
      $_POST=array();
      $schoolset=0;
      $url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
      wp_redirect(  $url  );
  exit;
}

}

    return;
}

//
// Sets up Session Variables


 function set_jamer_session ($postedschoolname, $postedschoollogin) {
  global $wpdb;
  global $wp;
    $schoolset=0;
    $tablename="schools";
    $tablename_all = $wpdb->prefix.$tablename;
    $querycode="select schoolid, password from $tablename_all where schoolid='$postedschoolname' and password='$postedschoollogin'"; 
      $rs=$wpdb->get_results($querycode); 
      $rscount=count($rs);

    if ($rscount=1) {
       $count=1;
       foreach($rs as $r) {
        $schoolid= trim($r->schoolid);
        $schoolidpassword= trim($r->password);
       }
        $schoolset=1;
        $tablename2="jamercookies";
        $tablename_all2 = $wpdb->prefix.$tablename2;
        $jamercookieid=$_COOKIE['jamer_session_id'];
        if(isset($jamercookieid)) {
          $wpdb->update($tablename_all2, array( 'schoolid' => $schoolid), array('jamer_session_id' => $jamercookieid));
       } 
           }
    return $schoolset;
}

//
function mc_find_schoolid() {
//alert ("Entered mc_find_schoolid") ;  

    global $wpdb;
    global $wp;
    global $woocommerce;
      $schoolid="No School Set";
      $jamercookieid=$_COOKIE['jamer_session_id'];
      if(isset($jamercookieid)) {
      $tablename="jamercookies";
      $tablename_all = $wpdb->prefix.$tablename;
      $querycode="select schoolid from $tablename_all where jamer_session_id ='$jamercookieid'"; 
      $rs=$wpdb->get_results($querycode); 
      $rscount=count($rs);
      if ($rscount=1) {
      $count=1;
      foreach($rs as $r) {
        $schoolid= trim($r->schoolid);
    }}}

    return $schoolid;
}
```

Comment: A new record is added to the database table every few minutes (not every time the page is loaded).  How can I stop ot doing that????

Comment: Sorted - moved the database call to a different function - all working as required